# How to better integrate Microsoft To Do with Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, to-do

I want to better integrate my Microsoft Outlook and To Do. Namely, when an event is added to the Outlook Calendar, I want it to automatically add the corresponding task to the Microsoft ToDo. I could only find flagged emails that can be added to the ToDo app but not calendar events.

I feel like this should be very trivial but searching the web has not yielded anything that is 
useful.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You may only be able to integrate To Do with Outlook tasks:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-microsoft-to-do-with-outlook-tasks-c7a0253d-b8cc-4054-b94b-c194e0e5308a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a cloud license of the Office, you can use [Microsoft Power Automate platform](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) (formerly Microsoft Flow) to create a server rule which will automatically create a task for every added event. Once you log into the platform, you can search for existing workflows (recommended – maybe such a flow is already there) or create your own with these properties

- Flow Type:
  `Automated`
- Condition name (type the name to start on-the-fly filtering of available options):
  `When an event is added, updated or deleted`
- Action name (type the name to start on-the-fly filtering of available options):
  `Create a Task`

If you created your custom flow, it may need some tweaking until it starts working satisfactorily but this is the way envisioned by the Microsoft on how to implement custom chains of actions in Office or any other platforms connected to their ecosystem.

Comment: worked like a charm with  a small modification. Thanks!

Comment: I have a small question, I followed the steps you had mentioned and everything works but there is a small issue. When I delete an event in the calendar, the corresponding to do task just becomes empty (it doesn't get deleted). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Morpheus – I would avoid *deletion* event by replacing existing condition `When an event is added, updated or *deleted*` with two other offered conditions: `When a new event is created` and `When an event is modified`. I am not sure if this can be accomplished within single flow or if your will need two separate flows, but the idea should be still achievable.